# Dataset of simple contracts with getter setters

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript

Are there any repositories/datasets which provide smart contract with simple logic like having some getters and setter functions. So, that I could give some values to  getter and setter functions, which make some changes on state variables and then i check the status of smart contract. If i download contracts from **etherscan.io,** then they have lot of complex logic. , In short, i want to test **bulk numbers of such simples contracts** on my on own ethereum blockchain with some default values (given through my program as per variable type used in contract).

Comment: What logic is there exactly in getter and setter functions, that you'd need a repository to provide that??? Also, these functions are specifically designated for the state-variables of a given contract, hence each contract would implement its own getters and setters, hence there's nothing that some common repository could contribute here.

Comment: simple logic, means for getter , just return  values of state variables (without asking/taking any parameter ) ... and for setter, just assign any values to state variable without considering roles, rights, owner address... I know such kind of contract could not exist... ACTUALLY, my utimate task is to interact with smart contract without understanding its logic from its source code.. Anyhow, thanks for your answer..

Comment: "getter , just return values of state variables" - 1. There is no logic here. 2. There is nothing here which can be implemented in some global repository which you can then use, because (as I explained in the previous comment) each contract has its own state-variables hence its own getter functions.

Comment: thanks for your time, i got it..

Comment: No problem :) ...